# Python read file

Tags: python

I'm kind of new to Stack Overflow and a beginner in programming.

I'm trying to read and display a text file with python, the problem is this:

Text file looks like this:

```
Header One

Header Two

1

2

3

4

etc. (no row should be in between)
```

And I want it to be displayed as:

```
Header one

Header two

1, 2, 3, 4, 5 etc
```

my code so far is, but I get everthing on the same line. Any ideas?

```
import csv

with open ("myfile.txt", "r") as csvfile:
reader = csv.reader(csvfile)

collected = []
for row in reader:
    collected.append(row[0])
print (",".join(collected))
```

Comment: Because you ask to do so with `join`.

Comment: Why are you using `csv` for something that doesn't appear to be any kind of CSV file?

Comment: csv stands for "comma separated values".. you can simply use file and read lines one by one.

Comment: Ok, but any suggestions how I can improve it without using CSV?

Comment: First note that you will have to print two lines directly. Take care of those, and then join the rest.

Comment: Can you show me what that would look like please?

Answer (score 1):

Open the file, print the first two lines, then either join and print the rest or unpack it and send it to `print()` with your desired separator. Don't forget to remove the linefeeds, since you want that content in a single line.

```
with open ("myfile.txt") as f:
    f = iter(f)
    for _ in range(2):
        print(next(f).rstrip('\n'))
    print(*(item.rstrip('\n') for item in f), sep=', ')
```